# SharedPreferences сохранение токена

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, token, authenticationtoken

Друзья, есть вопрос. Как мне сохранить токен который я получаю при регистрации в `SharedPreferences`, а после как его достать, для того, чтоб послать api get запрос. Я в java новичок, буду очень благодарен за ответ.

1. Посылаю запрос на сервер:

   ```
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("login")
   Call<Data> userLogin(
       @Field("login") String login,
       @Field("pass") String pass
   );
   ```
2. Получаю ответ ( модель), по идее в этом шаге токен приходит от сервера

   ```
   package com.example.diplomprogect.models;


   public class Data {
       private boolean status;
       private User data;
       private String token;

       public Data(String token) {
           this.status = status;
           this.token = token;
           this.data = data;
       }

       public boolean isStatus() {
           return status;
       }

       public User getData() {
           return data;
       }

       public String getToken() {
           return token;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Дальше создал файл с `SharedPreferences` и пишу чтоб токен сохранился:

   ```
   public void saveToken(Data token){
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

       editor.putString("token", token.getToken());

       editor.apply();
    }

    public Data getToken(){
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         return new Data(sharedPreferences.getString("token", null));
    }
   ```
4. Но, насколько я понял, чтоб токен сохранился мне еще надо что то написать в `LoginActivity`, а пока в файле `SharedPreferences`, `saveToken` и `getToken` подсвечены серым. Подскажите, что я должен сделать, чтоб токен сохранился?
5. Нужно создать запрос `GET`, в такой форме:

   ```
    @GET("users?token={{token}}")
    Call<UsersResponse> getData();
   ```

Где вместо `{{token}}` будет сохранённый ранее токен.

P.S. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать, я уже конкретно запутался. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: в студии есть проводник который дает возможность посмотреть файлы на устройстве, откройте вкладку, зайдите в папку data->data-> имя вашего пакета->shared_prefs-> и откройте файл вашего хранилища, там будет переменная token

Comment: покажите код где вы шлете запрос, это активность какая-то или как у вас это происходит?